# Add or subtract quantity as you click on the row of a table

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I need that when I click on the row of a table I add the amount and that when I click on that same row again I subtract the amount that I had added. I have managed to add it but I don't know how to make it subtract the amount when clicking again.

I have managed to make the selected row change color depending on whether I select it or not, but now I need what has been added (this if I have succeeded) to be subtracted if I click on the row again.

This is my html:

```
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let item of articulos; index as i" (click)="total(item.cantidad)"
                    (click)="cambiarFlag(item)" 
                    [ngClass]="{'seleccionada': item.selected, 'noSeleccionada': !item.selected}">
                    <td>{{item.articulo}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.cantidad}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.recogida}}</td>
                </tr>
                <br>
            </tbody>

        <div type="button" class="col border border-white border-4" id="other" type="button"
            routerLink="/entry-order-lines-quantity" style="background-color:rgb(3, 71, 150);">
            Cantidad {{totalCantidad}}
        </div>
```

This is my ts:

```
export class EntryOrderLinesComponent implements OnInit {
  totalCantidad: number = 0;

  articulos = [
    {
      articulo: '385/65X22.5 HANKOOK AH51 160K (3003836)',
      cantidad: 94,
      recogida: '0',
      selected: false,
    },
    {
      articulo: '385/65X22.5 HANKOOK TH31 164K (3003309)',
      cantidad: 60,
      recogida: '0',
      selected: false,
    },
  ];

  total(cantidad: number) {
    this.totalCantidad += cantidad;
  }

  cambiarFlag(item: any) {
    item.selected = !item.selected;
  }
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

When we need execute two functions we should use an unique "event" and separate by ";" the functions. Some like:

```
 <tr *ngFor="let item of articulos; index as i" 
    (click)="total(item.cantidad);cambiarFlag(item)">
```

Well, if always make the same, we can use an unique function

```
 <tr *ngFor="let item of articulos; index as i" 
    (click)="selectAndCalculateTotal(item)">
```

And use

```
selectAndCalculateTotal(item:any)
{
    item.selected=!item.selected;
    this.totalCantidad+=(item.selected)?-item.cantidad:item.cantidad;
}
```

Really, if you have a few elements (less than 50 or 100) it's better calculate the total using the array item instead use an auxiliar variable. It's worst perfomance but more "robust". So you can use a getter

```
get total()
{
   return this.items.reduce((a:number,b:any)=>{
     return b.selected?a+b.cantidad:a
   },0))
}
```

Comment: I was trying to do it more or less like this and it didn't work out. It has worked! Thank you!

Comment: if you get negative value it's not working :(. be careful when you change the "selected" variable and when you add/less the quantity.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I checked and fixed it. It has been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

since you have a filed holding the `selected` state of each item, you need to first check the state before deciding the action to perform. you can do that like this

```js
  
   total(item: any) {
     if (item.selected) {
       this.totalCantidad += cantidad;
       item.selected = !item.selected;
     }else {
       this.totalCantidad -= cantidad;
       item.selected = !item.selected;
     }
    
  }
```

this way you don't need to call two functions anymore. you can delete the other function to changing the state of `item.selected = !item.selected;`

don't forget to pass the selected item into `total(item)` in your html click action